# almost sure convergence of positive random variables with bounded expectation implies uniform integrability?

Tags: uniform-integrability, strong-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of positive random variables that converge almost surely to a constant $a$, and have bounded expected value $\mathbb{E}X_n=\mathbb{E}|X_n|<C$ for some constant $C$ and all $n$. Does this imply that $\mathbb{E}X_n\rightarrow a$?

Comment: Standard example: $a=0,X_n=n1_{(0,\frac  1n)}$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I don't understand your $X_n$, can you please explain? what values does it take with what probability?